# SqlConnection single instance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

```
    public static void firstConnection()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }


    public static void connectionTry()
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
```

If i cut firstConnection, the program crash because it doesn't find any instance of connection, so what i can do to delete the first function?

Comment: move connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); to the top of if condition

Comment: Ajoe it's right your connection variable isn't istanciated when you try to access to it so moving the  ` connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);` over the if statement will solve your problem. However you can just add also the `connection == null` condition inside the `if` statement if ypu don't want to recreate it each time you call the function

Comment: hint: you are looking for the singleton-pattern

Comment: I think you can just reopen the existing connection instance. If you set the instance null for cutting firstconnection there will be error in connectionTry function.